# Apple 360 Demo to only spin with X axis on ipad or mobile

Tags: javascript, safari, 360-degrees

I'm working with HTMl 5 Object VR solution from the apple Demo https://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/vr.php

I only have a 360 image that spins with X axis, and what I want the whole page to scroll when the user "touchemove" down or up on an ipad and not to spin the image.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If someone interested, this is how I resolved that issue.

On the script "vr_org.js" I did the following:

First commented the event.stop() on the **onGrabStart** function.

> onGrabStart: function(event){
>   ....
>   //event.stop();

Then on the **onGrabChange** function created two variables that would track the distance of both Y and X axis of the user move.

> var yDistance = parseInt(Math.abs(this.onGrabStart.clientY - event.clientY));
>   var xDistance = parseInt(Math.abs(this.onGrabStart.clientX - event.clientX));

Finally if the X distance is greater than Y distance, stop the default scrolling event.

> if(yDistance <= xDistance){
>     event.stop();
>   }